# MutationObserver does not detect new nodes made with .appendChild()

Tags: javascript

When you run this snippet in Chrome Developer Tools:

```
function callback(mutations, mutationObserver) {
    for (let mutation of mutations) {
        console.log(mutation);
    }
}

let mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(callback);

mutationObserver.observe(document,
                         {childList: true,
                          subtree: true});
```

The code will not work on https://twitter.com/twitter but it will on https://www.google.com/ when you `.appendChild()` or change the `.innerHTML` of a node.

What is causing the problem on https://twitter.com/twitter ? New tweets get rendered via `.appendChild()` but they don't show up in the console logs either.

Comment: Is it possible that twitter.com is overriding the global default `MutationObserver`? Or is it possible that an extension conflicts with your code on Twitter but not on Google?

Comment: This is probably something with twitter. For example: `https://twitter.com` > does not work | `https://twitter.com/i/flow/signup` > does work

Comment: @madara-uchiha, it is something else. `MutationObserver` shows up as `ƒ MutationObserver() { [native code] }` in the console and disabling all my extensions didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the mutations aren't showing up in the console logs is because Twitter is overwriting `console.log` with its own implementation.

You can verify this for yourself if you go to https://www.google.com/ / https://twitter.com/twitter and search for `console.log;` in the console.

On Google you'll get: `ƒ log() { [native code] }`.
Whereas on Twitter you'll get: `ƒ (){}`.

The mutations still get detected, though. You can verify this with this code snippet:

```
let mutationsCopy;

function callback(mutations, mutationObserver) {
    mutationsCopy = [...mutations];
}

let mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(callback);

mutationObserver.observe(document,
                         {childList: true,
                          subtree: true});
```

Now if we run in the console:
`document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));`

and search for `mutationsCopy;`, we'll get:
`[MutationRecord]`